# Dynamically changing css attribute value in HAML file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

My Haml file looks like :-

```
.playing-card-container
  .card-image
```

The CSS class for `.card-image` is

```
  .card-image {
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    background-image: image-url('some-url');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

The `haml` file gets **an image object from a rails server**, and I want to dynamically change the background image for `.card-image` class. I know how to dynamically add classes or ids but how can we change a certain **css attribute**? I will appreciate if you can provide any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(".card-image").css("background-image", url)
```

Edit: In HAML

```
.card-image{"style"=>"background-image:url(#{url});"},
```

Comment: If it's in the HAML file you can use `.card-image{style:"background-image: #{url} ;"}`

Comment: if you can modify your answer to `.card-image{"style"=>"background-image:url(#{url});"}`, I will accept it